# How to provide #defines to misra checking in cppcheck?

Tags: c, misra, cppcheck

I'm trying to utilize misra C:2012 checking in from cppcheck (v2.9). However, when executing on a particular file I get the following violations:

> vehicle_controller.c:1494:2: style: All identifiers used in the controlling expression of #if or #elif preprocessing directives shall be #define’d before evaluation. [misra-c2012-20.9]
> #if OS == LINUX_OS
> ^
> src/emb/bwk/

I'm using the following command to execute:

```
$ cppcheck -DOS=LINUX_OS --addon=misra.json vehicle_controller.c
```

Is there a different way to pass `#define` to be properly picked up by the misra checking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the examples within Rule 20.9, an undefined identifier results in a zero value:

```
#if OS == 0    /* Non-compliant - OS may be zero or undefined */
...
#endif
```

The MISRA compliant approach is to ensure that the identifier is defined before use. Thus:

```
#ifndef OS
...                   /* OS is undefined           */
#else
  #if OS == 0
  ...                 /* OS is defined as zero     */
  #else
  ...                 /* OS is defined as non-zero */
  #endif
#endif
```

Comment: I understand what the issue is. I'm asking how to pass the `#define` on the command line or in some type of configuration file.

I DO have `OS` defined before use.  It's part of our build configuration.  I'm trying to simulate that somehow on the command line or a config file used by cppcheck and/or misra.py

Comment: ``cppcheck -DOS=LINIX`` should work fine.  Are you sure that it is not defined? R.20.9 requires that you do check (as per my answer) and not assume.

Comment: Alternatively, `#if defined(OS) && (OS == something)` to ensure that each line is safe in itself, or to reduce the number of nested `#ifdef/#ifndef/#if`. Or yet another alternative: `#ifndef OS ... #elif OS == 0 ... #else ... #endif`.

Comment: @Andrew It's strange that when I use polyspace for misra checking, it doesn't flag this as an issue. I assumed because `OS` is defined as part of polyspace configuration.  If this method of syntax is required to make cppcheck happy for misra checking, then I probably can't use it.  That would require massive code refactoring unfortunately.

Comment: Given my affiliation, I won't comment on tools.  As the rule is *required* you can, of course, deviate with justification.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for all the info! Definitely helps to understand it more and understand intent of Rules!